# How can I show "jump to latest" in a RecyclerView list only when the view is scrolled such that latest entries are not visible?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-13

Is there a simple way to scroll back to latest entries in a `RecyclerView` only when latest entries are no longer visible (due to the user scrolling away)?

Ideally, I wish if there is a listener that can be put on the `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` that is called only when an entry is in a given position (e.g., say an entry in position `adapter.itemCount - 1` stops being visible).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a method that gets called only when the user-defined position goes out of view.

You can use the adapter's `onViewDetachedFromWindow` method. You get the view holder as the function parameter and based on `holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`, you can probably show or hide the "Jump to latest button".